# Node.js proxy for ws.audioscrobbler.com responds with 301 to www.last.fm

Tags: api, redirect, node.js, proxy, last.fm

I’m trying to use Node.js to set up a proxy to Last.fm’s webservices. The problem is that every request to ws.audioscrobbler.com gets rewritten to www.last.fm. So for example `$ curl http://localhost:8000/_api/test123` sends a `301 Moved Permanently` to `http://www.last.fm/test123`.

```js
var express = require('express'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

// proxy server
var lastfmProxy = httpProxy.createServer(80, 'ws.audioscrobbler.com');

// target server
var app = express.createServer();
app.configure(function() {
  app.use('/_api', lastfmProxy);
});
app.listen(8000);
```

At the same time `$ curl http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/test123` returns a regular `404 Not Found`. I’m not exactly sure what I’m missing here, or if I’m approaching this completely the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get a `301 Moved Permanently` is that ws.audioscrobbler.com gets an HTTP request with the hostname "localhost".

One solution is to let the proxy rewrite the hostname to "ws.audioscrobbler.com" before passing it on to the remote server:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var lastfmProxy = httpProxy.createServer(function (req, res, proxy) {
  req.headers.host = 'ws.audioscrobbler.com';
  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    host: 'ws.audioscrobbler.com',
    port: 80,
  });
}).listen(8000);
```